# What is the difference (in usage) between “wrong,” “incorrect,” and “inaccurate.”

Tags: word-usage

I searched on the web, but it is unfortunate that I was not able to find a clear and concise difference in the usage of “wrong,” “incorrect,” and “inaccurate.” I know there is a difference in their usages, but the answer seems to be too shrouded in mystery, as well as seemingly demoted in perceived importance by the public (even though it is very important) for there to be an easily available answer.

Comment: The fact is that words are 'infinitely polysemous' and overlaps between areas of usage slippery, open to argument, and hardly 'easily available'. Usage panels of seasoned Anglophones have bunfights over such issues. Thus here, the words are often non-interchangeable. 'This clock is wrong' means it's showing the wrong time whereas 'This clock is inaccurate' means that adjusting the time wouldn't help much. 'What he did was wrong' brings in the moral perspective. Information may be termed 'incorrect', but not usually 'wrong'. And then there is the issue of register./ What research have you done?

Comment: I've checked, and 'information is wrong' is not uncommon. However, I'd say that 'the wrong information' has a different default sense from 'incorrect information'. The former may be true but non-germane.